# Does paging let us use physical memory that is larger than what can be addressed by the CPU’s address pointer length?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

I was reading the dinosaur book on Operating System about memory management. I assume this is one of the best books but there's something about paging written in the book which I don't get.

The book says, "A 32-bit CPU uses 32-bit addresses, meaning that a given process space can only be 2^32 bytes (4 TB ). Therefore, paging lets us use physical memory that is larger than what can be addressed by the CPU’s address pointer length."

I don't quite get this part because if the CPU can only refer to 2^32 different physical addresses, if there were 2^32+1 physical addresses, the last address won't be able to be reached by the CPU. So how can paging help with this?

Also, earlier the book says "Frequently, on a 32-bit CPU , each page-table entry is 4 bytes long, but that size can vary as well. A 32-bit entry can point to one of 2^32 physical page frames. If frame size is 4 KB (2^12 ), then a system with 4-byte entries can address 2^44 bytes (or 16 TB ) of physical memory."

I don't see how that is even possible in ideal/theoretical situations, cuz as I understand it, part of the virtual address will refer to an entry of the page table while the other part of the virtual address will refer to the off-set of that particular type in that page. So in the above-mentioned situation put forward by the book, even if the CPU could point to 2^32 different page entries, it won't be able to read any particular byte within that page cuz it doesn't specify the office.

Maybe I've misunderstood the book or there is some part that I missed out. I much appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to burn your book. It's useless.

"[P]aging lets us use physical memory that is larger than what can be addressed by the CPU’s address pointer length" is complete nonsense (unless the book is assigning two different meanings to the term "paging," in which it is still useless).

Let's start with logical addressing. A logical address is composed of a page selector and and offset into the page. Some number (P) of bits will be assigned to the page selector and the remained will be assigned to the offset. If pages are 2^9 bits, there are 23 bits in the page selector and 9 bits for the byte offset within the page.

Note that the 9/23 pick are arbitrary on my part. Most systems these days use larger pages but these are values have been used in the past.

The 23 bits in the page selector are indices into the process page table.

The size of entries in the page table are going to be a power of 2 (and I have never seen one less than 4). For our purposes let's say that each entry is 8-bytes long.

The bits in the page table entry are divided between those that index physical page frames and control bits. let's make the arbitrary choice that 32 bits index page frames and 32 bits are used for control.

That means the system can theoretically MANAGE 2^32 pages that are 2^9 bytes large or a total of 2^41 bytes. If we were to increase the page size from 2^9 to 2^20, the system could theoretically MANAGE 2^52 (32+20) bytes of memory.

Note that each process can still only ACCESS 2^32 bytes. But in my 9-bit page system, 2^9 processes could each access 2^32 pages simultaneously on a system with 2^41 physical bytes of memory (ignoring the need for a shared system address space in this gross oversimplification).

Note that if I change my page table to 32-bits and assign 9 of those bits to control and and 23 to page frame selection, the system can only MANAGE 2^32 bytes of memory (and that was more common than managing greater than 2^32 bytes).

You quote: "Frequently, on a 32-bit CPU , each page-table entry is 4 bytes long, but that size can vary as well. A 32-bit entry can point to one of 2^32 physical page frames. If frame size is 4 KB (2^12 ), then a system with 4-byte entries can address 2^44 bytes (or 16 TB ) of physical memory."

This is theoretical BS. A system that used all 32 bites of the page table entry as an index to page frames could not function. There would have to be some control bits in the page table.

The quotes you are taking from this book are highly misleading. Few (any?) 32-bit processors could even access 2^32 bytes of memory due to address line limitations.

While it is possible that the use of logical pages could allow a processor to manage more memory that the logical address size suggests, that was not the purpose of managing memory in pages.

The purpose of paging—which in its normal and customary usage refers to the movement of virtual memory pages between physical page frames and secondary storage—is to allow processes to access more virtual memory than there was physical memory on the system.

There is an additional system of memory management that is (thankfully) dying out: segments. Segments also provided a means for systems to manage more physical memory than the logical address space would allow.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the answer! it quite confirms my own understanding, just I'm not as bold as you to passionately denounce the book since the book seems to be quite prestigious xD so it's good to know i'm not the only one who feels the book is weird.... 

the book is Operating System Concepts by Silberschatz, Galvin, Gagne, i hope other beginners can also get less misled by the book = =

anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Man $160 bucks on Amazon. There are copies of VAX/VMS Internals and Data Structures under $5 that would have better information, if dated.